# Opening new window with Post data (PHP, Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, post, window, request

I am trying to do the following, can someone please help.

I have created a php file that accepts json objects. This web page is meant to be displayed directly to the users.

How can I open this page from another page without using html forms? I need a easy solution that would look something like the following.

Javascript (with JQuery support if needed):

```
    var JsonParamToPass=jsonObj;
    var postData=JsonParamToPass;
    window.open("www.myAwesomePageThatAcceptsPostData.com",'_blank',method=POST,postData); 
  //the last two variables are made up and i need to find a way to do that, that can easily be given to other people to use.
```

I want to avoid using an ajax request and writing the output to a new page, and I want to avoid creating a form if possible.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have a really solid reason not to use Ajax and/or forms? In every case you will write the output to a new page. When the window is opened it is a new page, isn't it?

Comment: The reason is for ease of use for other people. This page is made to for other people to open and if it is not simple other people are not going to make use of it. If it were just me I would just use $.POST() and write the data to the newWindow. I am looking for a built in function for javascript/jquery or a way to have the browser made a post request (which i don't think most do)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the javascript window.opener method to access the parent windows variables.

```
var myVar = window.opener.parentVar;
```

Any reason you couldn't use a hidden form and submit it using javascript like this:
(this would be in your original window and document.submit would open a new window rather than using the current window)

```
<form name="myForm" action="http://yourAwesomePage" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="myVar" value = "">
</form>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    document.myForm.myVar.value = someValue;
    document.myForm.submit();
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: While this would work I am trying to make it simple for other users to do. I think the direction I am going to head is providing a javascript library and just having it accept the json variable. Then append a hidden form and submit it but I wanted to avoid make the users do too much work to open the window.